# Batch file for checking port status of multiple IP Address

Tags: windows, port, batch-file

How to check the port status of multiple IP Addresses from windows command prompt. I am looking for some Batch file or a Dos SCRIPT. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: You could probably do this with `PortQry`. Do you always need to check the same ports? UDP/TCP/Both?

Comment: PortQry is useful but how to make a batch script or portqry to read the host list from a txt file, exicute the command and send the result to -l log.txt file

Comment: Thnx all for the support, My requirement got solved by using PortQry.

Comment: i used the below in to the batch file.

Comment: set protocol=TCP
set port#=8080,4343,18443
for /f "tokens=1" %%V in (hs.txt) do portqry -n %%V -p %protocol% -o %port#%

Answer (score 3):

You could use nmap http://nmap.org to script something to check and list whats open on a given host or set of hosts

TiZon is right though, wed need to know more about what youre wanting to do before we could give a more concise answer.... Are you checking more than one host, the same ones over and over, more than one port, etc?

Just a wild assumption... If you want a robust monitoring and alerting system you could look at nagios www.nagios.org its free and does a great job monitoring and alerting for things like open / closed ports

Comment: Yes i am trying to find the status of multiple ports like 8080,4343 on multiple IP addresses i.e list of systems in a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I second nmap, but you can check for open connections with telnet

```
Telnet computer port
```

Such as:

```
telnet webserver1 80
```

Comment: i have to find the multiple port status for multiple IP address nearly about 400+ systems. I am looking for any simple batch script which can generate the status of port in to a log file.

Comment: This can be accomplished via a `for` loop given a list of servers, and at the end of the telnet command, append ">> filename.log" to the end of the command so that it appends the output to a file of your choosing (creating the logfile if it doesn't exist.)